# how to get SMP info (running on which core) for a specific process

Tags: linux, process, erlang, command

i have a question about Erlang.
how could i tell on which core Erlang beam is running on?
Or is there any Linux command that can tell the core where the process is running on if you supply the pid?
Can **top** work? but i don't want to observe it interactively. it would be better that i can extract the information through one command line. For example:
`top -b -n 1 -p <beam_pid>`
This could work, but i don't know how to add SMP info, i.e on which core...
Or, can i use **ps**, i don't know...
Can you help me?
Thank you in advance:)
Brs,
Ruan

Comment: Alternatively, you could also bind an Erlang scheduler to a logical core. That way you always know which cores are used by the Beam VM. See http://developer.vz.net/2009/07/30/about-erlangotp-and-multi-core-performance-in-particular-kenneth-lundin/

Comment: yeah, but i think a dynamic way maybe better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys, i found two ways that can work.
1) `ps -Ao user,pid,psr,cmd`, this could be used to see the SMP info for a pid.
2) this method needs extra steps. First, run `top`, and add field `P`. Then tap `W` to save the **top config file** as `~/.toprc`. Thus we can run `top -b -n 1 -p <pid>` to show the SMP info for a certain pid.
These ways work on CentOS, but not OSX... Any good idea is still welcomed:)